# Finding the number of binary numbers with k consecutive set bits

Tags: combinatorics

How many $n$ bit binary numbers have $k$ consecutive set bits? Does it have anything to do with the Fibonacci sequence?

Comment: The usual link to Fibonacci is the number of $n$ bit strings without two successive $1$'s. That has been on this site a number of times.

Answer (score 0):

I found a sloppy recursion: Classify each $n$ digit number not containing $k$ consecutive equal digits according to how many consecutive digits it ends with.

Call $f_{k,j}(n)$ the numbers that don't contain $k$ digits and end in exactly $j$ consecutive equal digits. One should notice $f_{k,n}(n)=n$ and $f{k,j}(n)=0$ when $n<j$ .Then one gets the recursion $f_{k,j}(n+1)=f_{k,{j-1}}(n)$. Also one gets $f_{k,1}(n)=g_k(n-1)$. Where $g_k(n)$ is the number of sequences of length $n$ not containing $k$ consecutive equal digits. Finally it should be clear that $g_k(n)=\sum\limits_{i=1}^k f_{k,i}(n)$.

What you want is $2^n-g_k(n)$